# No module named lstm_predictor

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

When I am trying to import the following module,

```
>>> from lstm_predictor import lstm_model
```

The error says no module named lstm_predictor.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This is not a standard module, did you install this correctly? https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it. You could also add your own answer if the existing one is incomplete / incorrect @Yannan.Liu

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are utilizing the `lstm_predictor` package present in https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series.

Since this is not a standard module, make sure you have cloned this project and you have the `lstm_predictor.py` file in the same folder as your python terminal.